# Automating VS Code 2017 Startup and Initialization

Tags: automation, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to automate the startup and initialization of VS Code 2017. I've been able to automate the installation using chocolatey and would like to now be able to get past the two splash screens:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to do this using powershell? So far, I am able to open it using:

```
start "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe"
```

to launch VS Code.